# Is there any way to put attributes at specific positions in a MongoDB document?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I have a mongo document with arrays and other attributes. Is there some way to show the arrays at the end or at a specific position inside the record?

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d1346df616b6529730b0000"), 
    "url" : [
        "URL 1", 
        "URL 2", 
        "URL 3"
    ], 
    "photos" : [
        "Photo 1", 
        "Photo 2"
    ], 
    "title" : "Lorem Ipsum Title", 
    "privacy" : "public", 
    "description" : "Lorem Ipsum description", 
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2019-06-26T10:20:15.753+0000"), 
    "created_at" : ISODate("2019-06-26T10:20:15.753+0000")
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will get result in order they stored in the collection.
As they are just JSON there is no need for ordering them because you are going to access them by keys.

but still if there is a need to do so, you can trick the collection by aggregation.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "title": "$title",
            "privacy": "$privacy",
            "description": "$description",
            "updated_at": "$updated_at",
            "created_at": "$created_at",
            "url": "$url",
            "photos": "$photos",
        }
    }
])
```

you will get result in same order you applied in `project`  pipeline.